# Circle not appearing when image is clicked, but works for others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 8 images on my page, 4 in one column and 4 in the other.

When I click on any of the images in the first column (panel1) I can see a circle appear on top of the image to show its been selected.

When I click on any of the images in the other column (panel2) the image fades out slightly but no circle is shown.

```
<div class="row col-xs-12 margin0">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 productmargintop5 paddingRound productsLeft">
        <div class="boxTop"></div>
        <div class="box" id="panel1">
                <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0" style="margin-left:-8%">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145153/black_cherries_snbvu8.png" data-id="1" alt="" data-name="blackcherry" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145152/coconut_psdlax.png" data-id="2" alt="" data-name="coconut" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
                <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0" style="margin-left:-8%">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="//res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145152/mango_p3tjp5.png" data-id="3" alt="" data-name="mango" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145152/strawberries_s1da7u.png" data-id="4" alt="" data-name="strawberries" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxBtm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 productmargintop5 paddingRound productsLeft" style="top:40%; left: 4%; position:relative"> + </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 productmargintop5 paddingRound productsLeft">
        <div class="boxTop"></div>
        <div class="box" id="panel2">
                <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0" style="margin-left:-6%">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145156/chocolate_lxphco.png" data-id="1" alt="" data-name="chocolate" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145156/cinnamon_o8nbos.png" data-id="2" alt="" data-name="cinnamon" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
                <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0" style="margin-left:-6%">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145156/honey_lawjsz.png" data-id="3" alt="" data-name="honey" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145156/vanilla_qptl2d.png" data-id="4" alt="" data-name="vanilla" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxBtm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 productmargintop5 paddingRound productsLeft" style="top:40%; left: 4%; position:relative"> = </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 productmargintop5 paddingRound productsLeft">
        <div class="boxTop"></div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="boxBtm"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my Script

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

         // Panel1 is working as expected      
         $("#panel1 .row img").click(function () { 
            $("#panel1 .row img").removeClass("BlackcherryCircle");
            $("#panel1 .row img").removeClass("CoconutCirle");
            $("#panel1 .row img").removeClass("MangoCircle");
            $("#panel1 .row img").removeClass("StrawberryCircle");
            $("#hdnPanel1").val('');

            var name = $(this).attr("data-name");

            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

            switch (name) {
                case "blackcherry":
                    $(this).addClass('BlackcherryCircle');
                    break;
                case "coconut":
                    $(this).addClass('CoconutCirle');
                    break;
                case "mango":
                    $(this).addClass('MangoCircle');
                    break;
                case "strawberries":
                    $(this).addClass('StrawberryCircle');
                    break;
                default:
            }

            $("#hdnPanel1").val(id);


        });


        // Panel2 has the issue it will not apply the CSS Class for the image clicked
        $("#panel2 .row img").click(function () {
            $("#panel2 .row img").removeClass("ChocolateCircle");
            $("#panel2 .row img").removeClass("CinnamonCircle");
            $("#panel2 .row img").removeClass("HoneyCircle");
            $("#panel2 .row img").removeClass("VanillaCircle");
            $("#hdnPanel2").val('');

            var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

            switch (name) {
                case "chocolate":
                    $(this).addClass('ChocolateCircle'); // Will not apply the CSS Class
                    break;

                case "cinnamon":
                    $(this).addClass('CinnamonCircle'); // Will not apply the CSS Class
                    break;

                case "honey":
                    $(this).addClass('HoneyCircle'); // Will not apply the CSS Class
                    break;

                case "vanilla":
                    $(this).addClass('VanillaCircle'); // Will not apply the CSS Class
                    break;


                default:
            }

            $("#hdnPanel2").val(id);
        });
    });
```

I have created a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Atkinson1988/5gdndpf9/) because I'm not 100% sure what is going wrong, the images that wont display the circle are inside panel2

Comment: what browser are you using? seems to be working in firefox. I can see the outline of the circle on my screen its very faint try changing the colour or opacity

Comment: @floor I'm using firefox v35.0.1, just checked in chrome and I get the same behavior, no circle appears

Comment: so you want circle on panel2 also?

Comment: @Rasel correct, so when they click on any image in panel 1 an circle appears which is working correctly, I want the same behavior on panel 2 so depending on what one they click will decide what class gets added to it via the switch case statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is the images... the images in the first panel has transparent background where as second one don't have transparent background.

So try to use images with transparent backgrounds

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145153/black_cherries_snbvu8.png" data-id="1" alt="" data-name="blackcherry" />
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424145156/honey_lawjsz.png" data-id="3" alt="" data-name="honey" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the images you've used in panel 1 have transparent backgrounds. In panel 2 the images have solid white backgrounds.